# Comma between "so" and "if"?

Tags: commas

Is it correct to have a comma after "*so*" when "*if*" comes right after it? Example: "*I visited California for a week. So[,] if you were wondering where I was, there's your answer.*"

Comment: Commas are often a question of style and intonation  that you want to give to the sentence. In your case I'd definitely use a comma.

Comment: It is very important to understand that it is neither correct nor incorrect to place a comma after _so_ in your sentence. For every person who will omit the comma, there is another person who will use the comma, and both of them will be correct.

Answer (score -1):

It's not always required, but it is correct in your example. In the case of your example, the section "if you were wondering where I was" is a separate thought or element, so it is offset from the rest of the sentence by the commas. It could be omitted or retained, and the meaning would be the same. Personally, I tend to put in commas quite frequently, wherever a spoken sentence might have a brief pause or a change in tone. I find it easier to parse the text that way.